# using multiple redis ports or instances with separate backup files

Tags: redis

I'm making new instances of redis by using different ports ([Multiple Redis Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644158/multiple-redis-instances))

How do I control where each port's dump.rdb backup file saves to?

Are both instances going to save to the same file? can I make separate backup files for each instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can have different configurations for each instance and use them like this:

```
$ redis-server /path/to/redis1.conf
```

Each [configuration](https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf) defines the filename for the dump file in the following setting:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump1.rdb
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**install_server.sh**](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/utils/install_server.sh) script from the Redis git repository to easily setup multiple servers with their own configurations (port, rdb directory etc...)